# Collocations with spaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I've been using NLTK for finding collocations, or n-grams, and have recently discovered the spaCy module for NLP. I've only just begun familiarizing myself with it and have, thus far, seen little mention for supported collocation functions.

Can spaCy be used to find collocations directly?

I have read through the [documentation](https://spacy.io/docs/), but haven't seen mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collocations detection also can be based on dependency parsing, but spaCy do not have support to do it. You can use spaCy as part of an approach, but not directly.

may you also consider gensim:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html

I hope it can help you