# Phrase extraction with Spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy, gensim, phrase

Does `spacy` have some APIs to do phrase* extraction as one would do when using `word2phrase` or the `Phrases` class from `gensim`? Thank you.

PS. Phrases meant as collocations in Linguistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am wondering if you have you seen [PyTextRank](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-pytextrank) or [spacycaKE](https://pypi.org/project/spacycake/) extension to SpaCy?

Both can help with phrase extraction which is [not possible directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40949414/6573902) with SpaCy.

Answer (score 4):

spaCy's [noun chunks](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#noun-chunks) feature is a useful form of phrase extraction, though quite different from gensim's Phrases or word2phrase.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Autonomous cars shift insurance liability toward manufacturers")
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk.text, chunk.root.text, chunk.root.dep_,
            chunk.root.head.text)
```

Output:

```
Autonomous cars cars nsubj shift
insurance liability liability dobj shift
manufacturers manufacturers pobj toward
```

You can also use the [rule-based matchers](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) to get other kinds of phrase defined by part of speech sequences, dependency relations, or other specifications.